# Automatic Semaphore release on process Exit

Tags: .net, process, semaphore

I am using Semaphore to limit the number of concurrent instances my application can run.

There are many ways a process can terminate.  Can the `Semaphore` be created so it automatically releases upon process exit?

EDIT:

I would like some magic to automatically clean up the semaphore 'raised' state for the process owning it upon exit or crash.  Just to be sure that it is cleared, no matter what.

MORE:

I am looking for any viable option for it, considering:

- it would be great that NO external application is required to get a hold on every instance of the protected application
- it doesn't have to be Semaphore - any synchronization object that has COUNTER and is AUTOMATICALLY released upon death of a owner process will be fine, even if it's cheating
- I am using .NET 2.0, can't move to newer version on this project, but can use c/c++ and inter-op to leverage something if there is something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hook into the [`AppDomain.ProcessExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) event to perform any cleanup operations like releasing the semaphore.

Generally, named semaphores are designed to coordinate resources across processes without taking particular process life-time into account. Semaphores in .NET are backed by [native Windows semaphore objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the MSDN says:

> The semaphore object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed. Closing the handle does not affect the semaphore count; therefore, be sure to call ReleaseSemaphore before closing the handle or before the process terminates.

Hence the right approach is explicit handling before process termination.

---

**Update** — Other options to consider:

1. In case it's not feasible to handle “emergency” release manually in the `AppDomain.ProcessExit` event, consider creating an `IDisposable` wrapper that would acquire the semaphore in its constructor and release it in the `Dispose` method.
2. Another question is: is a Semaphore the right synchronization object for this case? Wouldn't a simple (named) mutex work better?

---

**Update** — In case of an application crash or forced termination (i.e. via Task Manager) `ProcessExit` won't have a chance to be handled. Hence any unmanaged resources shared between multiple processes may not be finalized / disposed / handled correctly. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/11/26/process-exit-event.aspx) for further details.

A viable option may be [creating a *named pipe*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The advantage of named pipes is they cease to exit once the creating process is terminated. According to MSDN:

> Note that an instance of a named pipe may have more than one handle associated with it. An instance of a named pipe is always deleted when the last handle to the instance of the named pipe is closed.

There are two options to limit the number of pipe instances:

1. Just one instance:  By specifying the `FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE` flag in the `dwOpenMode` argument it is possible to prohibit creation of multiple instances of the pipe. Then, the second process attempting to create the pipe will receive an error.
2. More instances: By specifying the number of allowed instances in the `nMaxInstances` argument. When `N` are allowed, the `N+1`st process will receive an error.

Comment: Your answer is OK, but I would like some magic to automatically clean up the semaphore 'raised' state for the process owning it upon exit or crash.

Comment: Edited to provide more options.

Comment: Does named mutex have count?  I use this to limit number of program instances running (licensing)

Comment: No, they don't. In case you need count, Semaphores are the right option. For licensing, leveraging `AppDomain.ProcessExit` seems as the way to go. Or, wrap the contents of your main method (except the licensing system bootstrap) into a `using` clause wrapping the semaphore handling — see option (1) at the end of my answer.

Comment: @ondrey - this one still bites...  is AppDomain.ProcessExit ALWAYS called, no matter how the app exits (hangs/freezes, is terminated, ...)?

Comment: @DanielMošmondor I've described another method in my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @ondrey - looks promising, I'll try it!

Comment: @DanielMošmondor Hi Daniel, did you have a chance to give it a try? Was it working as expected?

Comment: Tonight I'm going to implement it and see what happens.  Wish me luck :)

Comment: thank YOU for that - that was EXACTLY what I was looking for, and was able to get away with oneliner at a start of the application!

Comment: Great to hear that and thanks for the bounty! I was lucky remembering named pipes and their properties — I used this technique 10 years ago. By the way, another less-known but great advantage of named pipes is they pass client identity as out-of-band data. The ImpersonateNamedPipeClient Win32 function allows the server to impersonate the client and act on behalf of its user account. Thanks to that it's even possible to open the user's interactive desktop and show windows even from a Windows service application.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that I'll be using pipes to my friend, and his response was that he uses it for the GUI-from-the-service task.  Anyway, great job :)

Comment: .NET offers Critical Finalizers for doing clean-up kernel objects, such as Named Mutexes and Semaphores. It doesn't require P/Invoke, it has been present since .NET 2.0 and is also available to Silverlight Apps. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate answer is to implement a 'Critical Finalizer' around your semaphore to ensure proper clean-up in all cases. ProcessExit is not guaranteed to execute in a failure scenario, such as a forced appdomain unload due to non-trappable exceptions (StackOverflowException and InvalidProgramException being two good examples.)

More info @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject.aspx, 
to quote: "the common language runtime (CLR) guarantees that all critical finalization code will be given the opportunity to execute, provided the finalizer follows the rules for a CER, even in situations where the CLR forcibly unloads an application domain or aborts a thread."

Answer (score 2):

If, unlike Daniel, you can upgrade to .Net 3.5 a [NamedPipeServerStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx) class is available to create your [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5232262/143503).

```
  NamedPipeServerStream pipe;
  try
  {
    pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(name, PipeDirection.InOut, 3);
  }
  catch (IOException)
  {
    //Maximum number of instances reached (3).
  }
```

I advice you to keep a static reference on the pipe to avoid Finalization before exiting the process.
The drawback of pipe is that you can't wait until an instance is available without polling.

Comment: As of .NET 4.6, there is [NamedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnectionAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823300(v=vs.110).aspx) and [NamedPipeClientStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823299(v=vs.110).aspx).