# How to notify the running thread that application is going to shut down in .net?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a requirement that, I need to run a method in the secondary thread(long running process), when the application is closing normally/abnormally I need to store the information of the secondary thread's method how much it is processed.

So when the next application starts I need to start the secondary thread's method from the point it is stopped.

Questions:

1. How can we achieve it?
2. How to intimate the thread that the application is going to shut down?

Comment: Which type of application are we talking about?

Comment: If there is a way to know when a process is killed abnormally, I would like to know also.

Comment: @AndreCalil: It is .Net windows application.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the best way would be to periodically save the progress of your secondary thread (to disk...) and resume from the last saved point when application (and your thread) is restarted.

Every other way seems like woodoo to me and will be hard to implement and debug.

Comment: +1 for checkpointing, a proven technique dating back decades.  Simple, robust, almost foolproof if implemented correctly.  It works regardless of whether the thread exited gracefully or was killed outright.

Comment: @Daniel Mosmondor: I agree with your point. The main thing I want to know is, how can we intimate the thread that the application is going down?

Comment: You can't - unless you get to some kind of magic.  I asked something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231569/automatic-semaphore-release-on-process-exit. You will see from the answers that there is no 'clean' way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In the secondary thread you could technically tie into the [AppDomain.ProcessExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) and [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) events.

A word of caution though, both of those events are last chance type events and have some caveats to them. A thorough reading of the MSDN docs on each event before using them is warranted.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you problem is a candidate for using a `BackgroundWorker`.  It provides for progress and cancellation notification.  Please see [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx.) docs for an example.

When you initiate or detect that the application is going to shutdown, you can call `CancelAsync` on the background worker instance.  Inside the handler for the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event, you can examine the event args periodically to see if cancellation is requested.